# send char from one program to another through pipe does'nt work

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am trying to run a program that does following actions:

1. Fork a child process that will launch another compiled c program-
   draw.out
2. The parent process then waits for user to input from keyboard
3. Input then passes to the draw.out program via a pipe
4. draw.out reads from pipe and uses the input

Here are the two programs, `draw.out` works fine (Tetris game) but isn't getting input from pipe, what is my mistake?

File 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    int     fd[2], childpid;
    //pid_t   childpid;
    char    input = 'o';
    char    readbuffer[80];

    pipe(fd);

    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (childpid == 0)
    {
        close(0);
        dup(fd[0]);
        execl("draw.out", NULL);


    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        while (input != 'q')
        {
            input = getch();
            if (input == 'a' || input == 's' || input == 'd' || input == 'w' || input == 'q')
            {
                write(fd[1], &input, 1);
                kill(getpid() + 1, SIGUSR2);
            }

        }
        exit(0);

    }

    return 1;
}
```

File 2:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void print_screen(int a, int b, int c, int t, int flat);
void my_handler(int signum);

int a = 9, b = 10, c = 11, t = 0, flat = 1;
int newfd = 0;

int main(void)
{


    if (signal(SIGUSR2, my_handler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        printf("Pærent: Unable to create handler for SIGUSR2\n");
    }
    while (t < 20)
    {
        system("clear");
        print_screen(a, b, c, t, flat);
        sleep(1);
        t++;
    }



}

void my_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGUSR2)
    {
        printf("signal arrived");
        char input;
        fgets(&input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        switch (input)
        {
        case 'a':
            if (a > 1)
            {
                a--;
                b--;
                c--;
            }
            break;
        case 's':
            t++;
            break;
        case 'd':
            if (c < 18)
            {
                a--;
                b--;
                c--;
            }
        case 'w':
            if (flat == 1)
            {
                flat = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (b<18 && b>1)
                {
                    flat = 1;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'q':
            exit(0);

        }
    }
}


void print_screen(int a, int b, int c, int t, int flat)
{
    char str[420] = "\n";
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            if (i != 19 && !(j>0 && j < 19))
            {
                strcat(str, "*");
            }
            else if (i == 19)
            {
                strcat(str, "*");
            }
            else
            {

                if (flat == 1 && i == t && (j == a || j == b || j == c))
                {
                    strcat(str, "-");
                }
                else if (flat == 0 && j == b && (i == t || i == t - 1 || i == t + 1))
                {
                    strcat(str, "-");
                }
                else
                {
                    strcat(str, " ");
                }
            }
        }
        strcat(str, "\n");
    }
    puts(str);
}
```

Comment: What is this `kill(getpid() + 1, SIGUSR2);`? Making an assumption here

Comment: `dup(fd[0]);` probably need `dup2` - http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2

Comment: `fgets(&input, sizeof(input), stdin);` this will be handling around not for a character. Perhaps `read` to mirror the `write`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you cannot read one byte with `fgets`. From `man fgets`:

> fgets()  reads  in at most one less than size characters from stream

As sizeof(input) is 1 "one less than size" is 0. Thus fets will read nothing. Change it to fgetc for example.

Second: `kill(getpid() + 1, SIGUSR2);` statement is obviously wrong, because you assume your child will have pid of your process + 1. This is wrong assumption, and there is no need of such construction, since you have `childpid` variable correctly set.

Third: You are not initalizing ncurses with `initscr()`, so `getch()` won't work. As this will also reconfigure your terminal add "\n\r" at the end of each line instead of "\n". And don't forget to de-initialize ncruses calling `endwin()` before exiting.

Fourth: Doing anything more complicated than getting/setting simple variables in signal handlers is generally a very bad idea. You should `poll` for the input in your main loop using `select` function, like this:

```
struct timeval time;
time.tv_sec = 0;
time.tv_usec = 0;
fd_set set;
FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(0, &set);
if (select(1, &set, NULL, NULL, &time) > 0) {
    handle_input();
}
```

Fifth: You're missing a `break` statement in your case, also both `d` and `a` keys are decrementing variables, while `d` should be incrementing I guess.

Here is the code that works:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_screen(int a, int b, int c, int t, int flat);
void handle_input(void);

int a = 9, b = 10, c = 11, t = 0, flat = 1;
int newfd = 0;

int main(void) {
    int t = 0;
    while (t < 20) {
        system("clear");
        print_screen(a, b, c, t, flat);
        sleep(1);
        struct timeval time;
        time.tv_sec = 0;
        time.tv_usec = 0;
        fd_set set;
        FD_ZERO(&set);
        FD_SET(0, &set);
        if (select(1, &set, NULL, NULL, &time) > 0) {
            handle_input();
        }
        t++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void handle_input() {
    char input;
    input = fgetc(stdin);
    switch (input) {
    case 'a':
        printf("a\n");
        if (a > 1) {
            a--;
            b--;
            c--;
        }
        break;
    case 's':
        t++;
        break;
    case 'd':
        if (c < 18) {
            a++;
            b++;
            c++;
        }
        break;
    case 'w':
        if (flat == 1) {
            flat = 0;
        } else {
            if (b<18 && b>1) {
                flat = 1;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 'q':
        exit(0);
    }
}


void print_screen(int a, int b, int c, int t, int flat) {
    char str[4200] = "\n";
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        if (i != 19 && !(j>0 && j < 19)) {
            strcat(str, "*");
        }
        else if (i == 19) {
            strcat(str, "*");
        } else {
            if (flat == 1 && i == t && (j == a || j == b || j == c)) {
                strcat(str, "-");
            } else if (flat == 0 && j == b && (i == t || i == t - 1 || i == t + 1)) {
                strcat(str, "-");
            } else {
                strcat(str, " ");
            }
        }
    }
    strcat(str, "\n\r");
    }
    puts(str);
}
```

Second file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void) {
    int     fd[2];
    pid_t   childpid;
    char    input = 'o';

    pipe(fd);

    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (childpid == 0) {
        close(0);
        dup(fd[0]);
        execl("draw.out", "draw.out", NULL);
    } else {
        close(fd[0]);
        initscr();
        while (input != 'q') {
            read(0, &input, 1);
            if (input == 'a' || input == 's' || input == 'd' || input == 'w' || input == 'q') {
                write(fd[1], &input, 1);
            }
        }
        endwin();
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ideally both processes would close all the pipe fds they don't use.